# Import firebase/firestore not working in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

When I `import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";` I get this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I have nothing inside my function component and only a `<div>hello</div>` in JSX.

Edit: The component in project-name/components/Header/index.js

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>hello</div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Called in pages/index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../components/Header";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Site Name</title>
        <meta name="description" content="made by..." />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <Header />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Firebase install: `npm i firebase`

It works when I import the component: `../components/Header/index`, but I get same error when I import the component in a Layout:

```
import Header from './Header/index'

const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: Can you show the enter code for this particular function either as a code snippet or an image.

Comment: @HittuDesai I edited the post with code snippet.

Comment: Try importing from "../components/Header/index"

Comment: @IrfanullahJan That worked! Thanks - but now when I put in a layout`<div><Header /><div>{children}</div></div>` I get the same error

Comment: Can you try importing react `import React from 'react';` ? and have you checked this [troubleshooting steps](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-element-type-is-invalid-expected-string-but-got)?